# Document Library not under /subsites/Lists

Tags: sharepoint-library

I have added a Document library using the below code 
the document Library is created under `/subsite/Documents`
its url is `/site/subsite/Documents`.

I used the same method to create a "Links" list  ,
the url for "Links" list is `/site.com/subsite/Lists/Links`.

tried for some other list like Discussions, custom list ..
all are created under lists  , theire urls are

```
/site/subsite/Lists/Discussions
/site/subsite/Lists/customlist
```

My question is when we are adding a Document Library, why is its url  is shown under subsites

```
/site/subsite/Documents
```

why not under `/Lists/`,  `/site/subsite/Lists/Documents`

```
                  Log.Add("Adding lists to Decision Type latest", url, LogType.DecisionType | LogType.Created);
                  SPListCollection lists = web.Lists;
                  Guid guid = lists.Add("Documents", "Documents", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                  SPList list = web.Lists[guid];
                  list.OnQuickLaunch = false;
                  list.Update();
                  Log.Add("Added shared Document list latest", url, LogType.DecisionType | LogType.Created);
```

Comment: I can't give you a why, that is just the way it is, for as long as I can remember, my experience dates back to the 2003 version.

Answer (score 1):

When adding list using this code,

```
lists.Add("Documents", "Documents", SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
```

You are not providing list relative URL which usually gets populated when we use Visual Studio for adding list features (at least in VS 2012 and above).

So just for the sake of keep you moving forward, you can use create a custom document library template (set it's ID as a custom list let say 10701 for example) using Visual Studio as a feature, deploy it as solution (don't need to activate it) and then use this code to create your list, which will give you the ability to set list's relative URL by code,

```
web.Lists.Add(
    "List Title", 
    "List Description", 
    "Lists/ListTitle",  // list Url
    "FeatureID",  // this going to be featureID of list you just created
     10701, //    // this going to be set in Elements.xml
     "121"); // Document Template
```

Still not sure why you get different List Url for different lists added by code e.g. for some you get lists/.. and for others you don't.